# Prince of Thieves

Tags: cipher

A mysterious thief spotted a girl with many gadgets and jewelries. After a few minutes, the thief attacked the woman and get all her gadgets and jewelries.

But there's a one gadget that the thief didn't get, an old model cellphone. The thief has this attitude after he successfully do a crime, he always leave a clue.

And the clue is the message he left on the cellphone.

> *Message*: **7 6 2 4 6 4 6 6 3**

Now, You are going to decode the message left by the thief.

*Hint:*

- one of the clues to decode the message can be found on the story.
- He is the prince of thieves.
- The content of the message is the name of the thief

NOTE: ( *You need to show how did you decode it, include also the clue that you found in the story.* )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the thief name is

> [robin hood the prince of thieves](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102798/)

The clue in the story is

> the old phone model with a physical keyboard

The anagram part is

> each number of the clue matching one key on a phone with multiple letters

So

> 7 match with pqrs but we choose r
>  6 match with mno but we choose o
>  and so on to find ROBIN HOOD

Comment: The clues from the numbers aren't an anagram, they're a cipher (of sorts). Can't really see where the anagram comes in (unless Dyrandz just made a mistake, it does look like English might not be their first language).

Comment: @GlenO, i'm sorry, my bad.. i already edited my post..

Comment: @DyrandzFamador - not a problem. I suspected that that's what might have happened. Just for future reference, anagrams are where you change the order of the letters, like going from "hello" to "loleh" or from "flier" to "rifle".